# Can someone explain me why i need to put Buffer.cler and CharBuffer.cler at the end of the code.Otherwise i get an error?

Tags: java

Look at the bff.clear and cbf.clear why do i need to put them in, when i update position od my bytebuffer in for-loop?I know that my code work when i put dat .clear - command but why is it necessary?

```
package skladiste_za_prikaz;

 import java.io.File;
  import java.io.FileOutputStream;
   import java.io.IOException;
      import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
 import java.nio.CharBuffer;
 import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;

 public class brojevi {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
File a = new File("C:\\Users\\Jovan\\Desktop\\omfg.txt");
    int[] niz = new int[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        niz[i] = i + 1;
    }
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(a);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    ByteBuffer bff = ByteBuffer.allocate(1000);
    FileChannel ch = out.getChannel();
    CharBuffer cbf = bff.asCharBuffer();
```

(return <-- no need for this)
    for (int i = 0; i < niz.length; i++) {

```
        int T = 0;
        for (int j = 1; j <= niz[i]; j++) {

            if (niz[i] % j == 0) {
                T = T + 1;
            }

        }
        if (T < 3) {
            String s = "" + niz[i];
            cbf.put(s);
            System.out.println(cbf.position());
            bff.position(2 * cbf.position());
            bff.flip();
            try {
                ch.write(bff);
                cbf.clear(); // without this it doesnt work
                bff.clear(); // without this it doesnt work

            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
try {
        System.out.println("File is writen " + ch.size() + ".byte");

    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

According to the javadoc;

> public final Buffer clear()
>
> Clears this buffer. 
>   Invoke this method before using a sequence of channel-read or put
>   operations to fill this buffer

Probably you're doing a read or put operation when you update position in for loop.